# How to document private (non public interface) by using appleDoc?

Tags: xcode, documentation, documentation-generation

recently I have learned how to use the appleDoc to do the documentation for my iphone project.

But what I realize is that AppleDoc only scan the head file of each class and based on the special comment format it creates the docSet and html.

My question is that how to let the AppleDoc looking after the .m file as well. Because for classes like viewController, quite a few logic are in the .m sectors and not be exposed in the head file. (I am asking this is because in Xcode5 if you hover over a private method and press "option" button xcode does show you a hover which contain the special comment you made. That's how I guess that there must be a way to transfer these description/comment into the docSet).

[image]

Anybody has some idea please help to give me some answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out there was a line in the script command which you need to remove.
It will include all the "*.m" files where all the "private" interface comments are kept.

[image]