# How to except private method from output using "appledoc"?

Tags: objective-c, appledoc

I am using appledoc to make document of Objective-C(iOS) static library.
Document is made for customer and I don't want to document private method.
How to prevent documenting private method?

Comment: Are you providing the private methods in the .h file?

Comment: No, private methods are defined in only .m file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to document private (non public interface) by using appleDoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085269/how-to-document-private-non-public-interface-by-using-appledoc)

Comment: I already checked that post and confirm --ignore flag. According to my nderstanding, --ignore indicate exception of files appledoc will search. I indicated --ignore "*.m" and appledoc avoid documenting all methods of .m file. I would like to except only private methods.